# Sitecore forms - How to override number validation message?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am using Sitecore 9.2 forms with OOB number field and number validator. Is there a way to override the default number validation message. The default message shows "The field Value must be a number.".

I am looking for something similar as described here, [How to change the required field validation message for Sitecore 9 Forms](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/how-to-change-the-required-field-validation-message-for-sitecore-9-forms)

Comment: Forms validation messages can be adapted/translated in the items in `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations`. But are you sure you are only using ootb things?  I can't seem to find that error message...

Comment: I agree with @Gatogordo! OOTB number field only allowed number, please make sure this is not a custom one.

Comment: Yes, it allow only number. However there are exceptions like 'e',+,- and '.' That was allowed for decimal numbers and scientific notation(like 1.23e+10). However user can enter any of this chars and the default error message shows that "The field Value must be a number."